# GWT Modlue Restarts cause Out of Memory Error

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I'm developing a GWT application, and I'm having issues with testing in development mode in eclipse.

When I make changes to the client-side code, I refresh the browser page (F5) to reload the module. Every time I do this (whether the code has changed or not), the Development Tab in eclipse shows a new bullet point with "Module xxxx has loaded". As well, according to Task Manager, every time I do this, the javaw.exe host process increases by about 1MB of memory. Eventually (10-20 refreshes later), the page fails to load and the Development Mode tab shows this error:

`Out of memory; to increase the amount of memory, use the -Xmx flag at startup (java -Xmx128M ...)`

I can fix this by stopping and restarting the server (not the little refresh button in the Developer Mode tab, but the red stop button), but it then the module has to be revalidated, which takes a while. It seems that eclipse doesn't realize I've finished with the old module when I reload a new one. I'm observing the same behavior with a brand-new GWT project, so I don't think it's my code. Is anyone aware of a way to remedy this?

**EDIT**: See *both* answers below for possible solutions.

Comment: Obviously I realize I could just increase the memory, but the process and eclipse are already taking 1/2 a GB each, so I don't really want to give them any more memory.

Comment: What would be the relevant VM arguments for 4GB of RAM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default settings gwt dev mode use are the minimum , so you hit an out of memory really quickly.

[image]

From this you can see that the permgenspace is to low and if you refresh 20 times in a short periode it will go out of memory.

you can start by using following vmargs :

```
-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

But as enrybo pointed out if your application grows it requires more memory:

```
-Xms512m -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Comment: What would be the relevant VM arguments for 4GB of RAM

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really all that much you can do. As you mentioned you can increase the memory but eventually you'll run into the same problem even with more allocated memory.

I suggest you try to run in [Super Dev Mode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/superdevmode) but in that case you'll need to update the SDK you're using to `2.5.1+`. With Super Dev Mode your browser does not need a plugin because it will actually be running true Javascript. You even have the ability to debug in your browser but looking at your Java source (using source maps).